# What is the default ingress controller type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

We are deploying azure ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name1
  annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
```

---

If we do not explicitly mention ingress class(`kubernetes.io/ingress.class:`) in the manifest, what would be the default ingress controller type?

Nginx documentation says default as N/A.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify any ingress class explicitly, the value is omitted. You can specify a default ingress class for your cluster as you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class).

You should also migrate to the IngressClassName field as the [annotation is deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation).

Comment: When you say "value is omitted", do you mean, manifest does not function as ingress, after deployment?

Comment: yes, they will not function without an ingress class specified.

Comment: How to use `watch-ingress-without-class` flag in the above manifest?

Comment: this need to be passed on the ingress-nginx deployment and not the ingress manifest. also keep in mind: It is recommended though, to specify the default IngressClass.

Comment: if you are using the helm chart, you can configure it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L75